# P(AorBorC) given certain dependencies of A, B and C

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

Suppose that E, F, and G are events with  P(A)  =  19/100,  P(B)  =  7/25, P(C)  =  3/10. Furthermore, suppose A andB are mutually exclusive,  A and C are independent, and  P(B | C)  =  11/15. Find  P(A ∪ B ∪ C).

My attempt is as follows:

P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(B and C)

Now replace the P(B and C) with bayes theroem

P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) -P(B|C)P(C)

Which gave me 11/20.

I suspect I am misunderstanding the connection of conditional probability between B and C in this question. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've lost the $P(A \cap C)$ term when expanding $P(A \cup B \cup C)$, which is equal to $P(A)P(C)$ since $A$ and $C$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$\textsf{P}(A\cup B\cup C)=\textsf{P}(A)+\textsf{P}(B)+\textsf{P}(C)-\textsf{P}(A\cap B)-\textsf{P}(A\cap C)-\textsf{P}(B\cap C)+\textsf{P}(A\cap B\cap C)$$
Now, $\textsf{P}(A\cap B)=\textsf{P}(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ since $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Also, use that $\textsf{P}(A\cap C)=\textsf{P}(A)\textsf{P}(C)$ and that $\textsf{P}(B\cap C)=\textsf{P}(B\mid C)\textsf{P}(C)$.